# Split output of .serialize() and create an insert statement for every splitted part

Tags: php, jquery, sql, split

I have 3 tables and an output string from `.serialize()`.

*Tabel 1:*

```
parameter (parameterid, parametername)
```

*Table 2:*

```
parametervalue (parametervalueid, parameterid_fk, appid_fk, parametervalue)
```

*Table 3:*

```
app (appid, ..., ...)
```

`.serialize()` Output:

```
4=Test&6=This is a test&9=19&15=Bla Bla Bla&appid=19746

4 = parameterid, Test=parametervalue, appid=19746
```

For every "part" of the serialize output, I want to make an `INSERT` statement, that will add the `parameterid`, the `appid` and the `parametervalue` into the table `parametervalue`. How can I split this and add it dynamically? The "split" should be done using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str):

```
$str = '4=Test&6=This is a test&9=19&15=Bla Bla Bla&appid=19746';
$result = array();
parse_str($str, $result);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [4] => Test
    [6] => This is a test
    [9] => 19
    [15] => Bla Bla Bla
    [appid] => 19746
)
```

And now, to do the `INSERT`, you can loop through the splitted array:

```
foreach ($result as $part) {
    // do the INSERT
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/50489)

Comment: The IDs are wrong. In your SO answer they are 0-4, in the example they are the correct `parameterid`s  :)

Comment: @doonot: Ah, you're right. I missed that. I've now edited my answer to reflect that. Thanks!